# How show process dialog for get data from Sqlite and show in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, progressdialog

I want to when the button is clicked, a dialog processor is displayed as long as the list view full list after the jump view the other processor lines to be displayed.For low data, smart phone works fine, but if the data is too large to display in the list view and the list view smart phone hangs a bit when filled. please guide me .

this code

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


         openandquery();
        displayResultList();



        }
    });


public void openandquery() {

     baseHelper= new DataBaseHelper(contex);
     boolean exists=  baseHelper.checkDataBase();


      if (exists){

     message.messages(contex, "True : There database ");

        try {
            boolean open= baseHelper.openDataBase();


                  if (open)
                  {
                  message.messages(contex, "True : database open");

                      Cursor cursor= baseHelper.getTestData(edittext.getText().toString());
                        countf=cursor.getCount();
                      if (countf<=0)message.messages(contex, "Not Found");
                  }

                      else 
                      message.messages(contex, "False : NO database open");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            message.messages(contex, "Error Open  : " + e.getMessage());

        }   


      }

         else 
                  message.messages(contex, "False : There is no database");

    }





private void displayResultList() {

        try {

        array=baseHelper.results;
        tView.setText("Size : " +array.size());

            try {


                 arrayAdapter=new display();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
             message.messages(contex, e.getMessage());
            }

            listV.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
             message.messages(contex, e.getMessage());
        }



        }
```

this code called in openandquery

```
 public Cursor getTestData(String phone)
    { 

        String  sql ="SELECT * FROM cusomer WHERE address!='' and key='"+p;
         message.message(mContext, ":"+p+":");
        try
        {
             if (p.isEmpty())
             {sql="SELECT * FROM cusomer WHERE address!=''";


             }


            Cursor mCur = mDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);

            message.message(mContext, mCur.getCount()+"");
            if (mCur!=null)
            {

                if (mCur.moveToFirst()){
                              try {

                    do{
                          String d=mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                          String p= mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("phone")); 
                          int    k=mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("key"));
                          int    i=mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                          long t=mCur.getLong(mCur.getColumnIndex("registertime"));

                          results.add(new msgstore(d,p,k,i,t));


                      }while(mCur.moveToNext());



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    message.message(mContext, e.getMessage());

                }
                }

           mCur.close();

            }



                return mCur;





        }
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            message.message(mContext, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());

            throw mSQLException;
        }






    }
```

Comment: 100,000 records are impossible to scroll through on a smart phone. There is no situation where you actually need to put all these records into the list view at once.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following to your onClick function:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourListActivity.this);        
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setTitle("Updating values");
    dialog.setMessage("Searching the database");
    dialog.show(); // Show the dialog

    openandquery();

    dialog.setMessage("Loading results"); // if you want to change the message

    displayResultList();

    dialog.dismiss(); // Close the dialog.

    }
});
```

Comment: It does not work, I use it, then the list will show you full view,Thank u

Comment: @Negar, nothing apears on the screen? Or do you want to show it in a different time?

Comment: Nothing screen is not displayed

Comment: @Negar, maybe the time between clicking the button and when the list is full is too small, so you won't have time to see the dialog! Does the list take long to be filled?

Comment: No, when so much that makes the smartphone a little hang because the data is large (more than 100 thousand records) That's why I want to get the dialog processor that the user does not notice the Hong smartphone.